# Updating Table using 1 button

Tags: php

i want to use 1 update button to update a whole table ... ive been doing a code using update but the the php i made seems to need an update button per row i want to update the whole table only using 1 button ..

```
<?php
$username = "root";
      $password = null;
      $host = "localhost";
      $dbname = "newspaper_system";
      $conn = new mysqli($host,$username,$password ,$dbname);
    if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
    mysqli_connect("localhost","root", $password  ) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    mysqli_select_db($conn,"newspaper_system") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
if(!$conn){
    die("cant connect db". mysqli_error());
}
if(isset($_POST['update'])){

    $updatesql = "UPDATE newspaper_library SET Newspaper='$_POST[Newspaper]', Price='$_POST[Price]', Pricepersquare='$_POST[Pricepersquare]' WHERE News_ID='$_POST[hidden]}'";
    $conn->query($updatesql);
    print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
    print 'alert("UPDATE successful")';
    print '</script>';  

}   
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM newspaper_library") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
echo "<center><table class='CSSTableGenerator table table-bordered table-hovered' border=1>
<tr>
<td width = 200><label1>News ID</td>
<td width = 200><label1>Newspaper</td>
<td width = 200><label1>Price</td>
<td width = 200><label1>Pricepersquare</td>

<td width = 200><label1></td>

</tr>";
while($record= mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<form action=Newslibrary.php method=post>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width = 200> <label>". $record['News_ID'] . " </td>";
    echo "<td width = 200>". "<input type=text name=Newspaper class='form-control'  value =\"" . $record['Newspaper']. "\"> </td>";
    echo "<td width = 200>". "<input type=text name=Price class='form-control' value=\"" . $record['Price']. "\"> </td>";
    echo "<td width = 200>". "<input type=text class='form-control' name=Pricepersquare value=\"" . $record['Pricepersquare']. "\"> </td>";
    //echo "<td width = 10>". "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['News_ID']. "> </td>";
    echo "<td width = 200>". "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['News_ID']. "><input  type='submit' class='btn btn-default'  name=update value=update " . " </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";     


}
echo "</table>";

$conn->close(); 

?>
```

Comment: Take the form tag out of the while loop. Put it around the whole table.

Comment: nothing really changed :/

Comment: You'll also have to change the names of the inputs to account for multiple values and then change the back-end code to loop through the submitted values. Eg change `name=Newspaper` to `name="Newspaper[];` PHP will understand that you're passing it an array. Do a `var_dump($_POST);` if you're curious as to what's being sent. I'd you only want to update certain rows at a time, you'll need to have some javascript disable the `<input>` tags.